# tensorflow evalutaion and earlystopping gives infinity overflow error

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, overflow

I a model as seen in the code below, but when trying to evaluate it or using earlystopping on it it gives me the following error:

```
    numdigits = int(np.log10(self.target)) + 1
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

I  must state that without using `.EarlyStopping` or `model.evaluate` everything works well.

I know that `np.log10(0)` gives `-inf` so that could be a potential cause, but why is there a `0` there in the first place and how can it be prevented? How can this problem be fixed?

NOTES

this is the code I use:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

TRAIN_PERCENT = 0.9

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(100,), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(100)
])

earlystop_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(min_delta=0.0001, patience=1
                                                   , monitor='accuracy'
                                                   )

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="mse", metrics=['accuracy'])

X_set, Y_set = some_get_data_function()
sep = int(len(X_set)/TRAIN_PERCENT)
X_train, Y_train = X_set[:sep], Y_set[:sep]
X_test, Y_test = X_set[sep:], Y_set[sep:]

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=5, callbacks=[earlystop_callback])
ev = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
print(ev)
```

X,Y sets are  `np` arrays. X is an array of arrays of 100 integers between `0` and `10`. Y is an array  of arrays of 100 integers, all of them are either `0` or `1`.

Comment: `sep` should be `int(len(X_set)*TRAIN_PERCENT)`

Comment: @meTchaikovsky This unexpectedly seems to solve the problem. Thank you, but why did it cause this in the first place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well it's hard to tell exactly as I can't run code without `some_get_data_function()` realization but recently I've got same error when **mistakenly passed EMPTY array** to `model.evaluate`. Taking into account that @meTchaikovsky comment solved your issue it's certainly due to messed up input arrays.

Comment: +1 because sometimes you try to do things like use 95% of your data to train, 10% to validate, and wonder why it fails when trying to test with the rest of the data...

Answer (score 3):

in my case, the data was small - so doing something like

```
cached_train = train.shuffle(100_000).batch(8192).cache()
cached_test = test.batch(4096).cache()
```

would have resulted in an empty `cached_test` ! this does not affect `model.fit`

so always check the length of the data using `cached_test.__len__()` to make sure you are not passing an empty data to the function.